# How do i grab numbers from a Table on a website in my Cocoa App?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, html-parsing, data-mining

Ok this is a more specific version of my last question.

So on a website there exists some data that is coded in HTML into a table.

In my Cocoa app, I want to download the html code of the website and then read through the html and snag the data from it. I was hoping someone could point out some useful classes/methods for accomplishing the retrieval of the website and putting it into some format where I can read through the code in my program?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [hpple](http://github.com/topfunky/hpple), it's an HTML parser for ObjC.

here's an example using it:

```
#import "TFHpple.h"

NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@"example.html"];

// Create parser
xpathParser = [[TFHpple alloc] initWithHTMLData:data];

//Get all the cells of the 2nd row of the 3rd table 
NSArray *elements  = [xpathParser search:@"//table[3]/tr[2]/td"];

// Access the first cell
TFHppleElement *element = [elements objectAtIndex:0];

// Get the text within the cell tag
NSString *content = [element content];  

[xpathParser release];
[data release];
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks like a good way to go about this. I'm sure this sounds dumb but how do I actually get hpple into my application bundle?

Comment: Theres an INSTALLATION at the bottom page of the link. If you search the net, I am sure you can find example projects using hpple. You will need to ad libxml2, and a few other libraries and frameworks, but do a little more reading to better familiarize yourself with this wrapper.